# Why does HTML tags look so different for audio, video, and img elements?

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML so apologies if this is a dumb question.

In HTML, a video element looks like this:

```
<video src="https://example.com" controls>Label or text to display</video>
```

An audio element looks like this:

```
<audio>
  <source src="iAmAnAudioFile.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

And an image element looks like:

```
<img src="image.png">
```

Is there a rationale for all these to use such a different syntax from each other? Why don't they just all look the same, like:

```
<img src="https://example.com" attribute1 attribute 2>This could be alt text or be empty</img>
<audio src="https://example.com" attribute1 attribute2>This could be alt text or be empty</audio>
<video src="https://example.com" attribute1 attribute2>Label or text to display</video>
```

I understand that each element has different needs (like video needs to display text if the browser can't display the video), but it seems like those could be accommodated in a unified syntax.

Comment: `<audio>` and `<video>` elements actually do support both `src="..."` and `<source>`.

Comment: Pro tip: introductions like *"I'm new to HTML so apologies if this is a dumb question."* are not recommended and are not necessary.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<video>` and `<audio>` are actually unified.

You can very well have

```html
<video>
  <source src="thesource.mp4">
</video>
```

as well as

```html
<audio src="thesource.mp3" controls>Some fallback text</audio>
```

They both have a few attributes that will differ, but most are shared.

For still images, the equivalent element would be [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#the_type_attribute) and not `<img>`,  though it can't have its own `src`.

`<img>` is a very old element, from an other era, which explains why it's not designed the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good reason. You can have multiple `<source>` elements inside an `<audio>`, or indeed a `<video>` element, so the syntax is in fact consistent (`<img>` only allows one source however, so only `src` is supported). And if there is only one source, you can indeed use the `src` attribute for `<audio>` as well.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source

> It is commonly used to offer the same media content in multiple file formats in order to provide compatibility with a broad range of browsers given their differing support for image file formats and media file formats.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about how the img tag doesn't have a closing tag?

Since the  element cannot have any child nodes, it is defined as EMPTY and the end tag is forbidden (as it would serve no purpose).

The audio opening tag and end tag is on a new line I see in your example, but that doesn't matter, as long as it is closed. New line or on the same, it's the same.